# What does $e^{-iAt}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I'm trying to understand an algorithm, to solve $Ax = b$ linear equations.

But there is an equation, which I can not understand: $e^{-iAt}$ 
What does it mean, to calculate the $-iAt$ power of $e$ ?

Comment: use the series expansion:$ e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential):

$$
e^A = I + A + \frac12 A^2 + \frac 1{3!} A^3 + \cdots
$$

You can check for yourself that it satisfies the important property:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} = Ae^{tA} = e^{tA}A
$$

Comment: This is not valid for every matrix $A$.

Comment: @Kim: Why isn't it?

Comment: I used to know that the exponential matrix series is valid only when you know all the powers of $A$, namely $A^{2n}$ and $A^{2n+1}$ (even and odd powers).

For example if you have a matrix $A$ such that $A^{2n} = A$ and $A^{2n+1} = (1 + A)$ you can develop the exponential matrix in series..

Or am I wrong?

Comment: @KimPeekII The power-series is the *definition* of what is meant by $e^A$. A definition cannot be wrong.

Comment: @Winther A definition _can_ be wrong if it's based on faulty assumptions.  The definition of $e^A$ is not the power series, it's the matrix that the power series converges to.  Since the power series always converges, this definition is fine, but that's something that we should really verify if we're being rigorous.

Comment: @KimPeekII We can always calculate the matrix exponential explicitly by making use of the characteristic polynomial to write the higher powers in terms of finitely many lower ones.  Perhaps even better is to put the matrix in Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear, but for the $-iAt$ power of $e$, I'm going to assume that $i$ is the $\sqrt{-1}$ so that the expression is an combination of a real and an [imaginary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) as you can determine from the series expansion. Think of the real numbers as being on the the x-axis and the imaginary numbers being on the y-axis. Relationships using real and imaginary numbers happen in all sorts of scientific problems.